# My API can be read but I can't output in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I think the problem is the value is still null I need to set value but I don't know how.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jsonReturnedValue: null
    }
  }
```

in this area I set the value as null and tried fetching it to my react but when I run it only the "list of employees" can be seen

```
fetch("http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails")
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json()) .then(json => {
        this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: response.results });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
   
    }
    }

render() {
    return(
        <div>
        <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
          <h1>{ this.state.jsonReturnedValue }</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: Response is not available in your .then , but json, console.log(json) in the .then callback and then you can see what result you wanna set to jsonReturnedValue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `response.results` as `response` is not available in the third `then` call, only the second.

Try:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails")
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: json.results });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use axios for http request. and check in then promise using console.log(response); response is comming from api or not

Answer (score 0):

Does the `fetch` function stay in your `componentDidMount()`? Like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
    this.setState({jsonReturnedValue: JSON.stringify(resp)});
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Please also take notice that `this.setState({jsonReturnedValue: JSON.stringify(resp)})` => a stringified version of the `resp` must be used when you just want to dump it and see. (because in the `render()`, you just returned `<h1>{ this.state.jsonReturnedValue }</h1>` )

However, you may loop (perhaps using `.map`) the jsonReturnedValue and render each of your employee properly, then please remove the `JSON.stringify`